# javascript checking path already exists

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how would i check if the file path already exists in javascript

Comment: What kind of path? on a local or remote location?

Answer (score 1):

If the path you want to check for existence is on the server you cannot do it using pure javascript. You could set a controller action which returns JSON data indicating if the path exists on the server. This action could be invoked using AJAX:

```
public ActionResult PathExists(string path)
{
    return Json(new { result = Directory.Exists(path) });
}
```

Remark: beware of the security implications by writing such a method.

If the path you want to check for existence is located on the client machine then this cannot be done unless the client installs some specific plugin (ActiveX, Flash, Silverlight, ...).